# Want to establish connection with server test.mosquitto.org , using MQTT paho client with ssl. I am getting failed to connect

Tags: c, ssl, mqtt, paho

This is the code which I am currently running idk where I have committed mistake, getting error """"Failed to connect, return code -1""""
Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am running this in raspberry pi ,thanks in advance

```
#include <MQTTClient.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ADDRESS "ssl://test.mosquitto.org:8884"

#define CLIENTID "c1"
#define TOPIC "ack"
#define PAYLOAD "Hello World"
#define QOS 1
#define TIMEOUT 10000L

void MQTTClient_global_init (   MQTTClient_init_options *   inits   );
int main() {

  MQTTClient client;

  MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
  MQTTClient_SSLOptions ssl_opts = MQTTClient_SSLOptions_initializer;

  MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
  MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
  int rc;

  MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_DEFAULT,
                    NULL);

  conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
  conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

  conn_opts.ssl = &ssl_opts;
  conn_opts.ssl->trustStore = "client.crt";
  conn_opts.ssl->keyStore = "client.key";
  conn_opts.ssl->CApath = "mosquitto.org.crt";

  conn_opts.serverURIcount = 0;
  conn_opts.serverURIs = NULL;

  if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
  pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(PAYLOAD);
  pubmsg.qos = QOS;
  pubmsg.retained = 0;

  MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
  printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n"
         "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
         (int)(TIMEOUT / 1000), PAYLOAD, TOPIC, CLIENTID);
  rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
  printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
  MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
  MQTTClient_destroy(&client);

  return 0;
}
```

output:
Failed to connect, return code -1

Comment: If you look at the output of `ss -ltpn`, is there anything listening on port 8883? The default seems to be 1883.

Comment: LISTEN              0                   100                  0.0.0.0:8883                               0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN              0                   100                   [::]:8883                                     [::]:*   @AKX

Comment: Probably you can get some more Information on the brokers log file. On why the connection wasn't established. Also if you look at a Wireshark Trace you can look on where the Handshake fails. This would enable some Debug Output on patho it self: https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/tracing.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the source for Paho](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/3b7ae6348bc917d42c04efa962e4868c09bbde9f/src/MQTTClient.c#L1686-L1701), the easiest way you can get the `-1` error is by forgetting to initialize the library.

You will need to call [`MQTTClient_global_init`](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/_m_q_t_t_client_8h.html#a21804ede1a506d1d69a472bc30acc8ba) at the start of your program.

Comment: even though I have added , getting same error @AKX